# Changing font for multiple Labels in Xcode storyboard

Tags: objective-c, fonts, label, xcode-storyboard

How could I change font and colour of text for MULTIPLE Labels (all in one `UIViewController`) with one code, without having to make an `outlet` for every Label. I'm using `storyboards`.

Font has to be changed in code because it is not listed with all the others

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `IBOutletCollection` instead of many `IBOutlets`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UIView) NSArray *fontViews;
```

And then set the fontsize or whatever you want in a loop:

```
for (UITextView *view in self.fontViews) {
        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setFont:)]) {
            [view setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:20]];
        }
    }
```